# A laptop key stuck, on log logon, how can I determine which key is it?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard

On the Windows XP login, the password text box is being typed automatically, it appears a key is stucked everytime I boot. I'm able to login to Windows so I open Notepad immediately to determine which key is but it appears to problem is gone and only happens on boot. Is it possible to find out which key is it?

Comment: Install a key logger!

Answer (score 1):

Disable fast user switching(control panel -> user accounts, you must be administrator to do this) and use "user" input box on classic login screen to see what key is stuck.

Comment: Apparently it stops when I use the username input box

Comment: Open notepad and try to reconnect the keyboard, maybe it will behave like after boot.